# Resizing elements and browser window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a container with multiple buttons which are absolutely positioned. I would like these buttons to resize according to browser window width. So button size and its position should change.
It looks little like a checkboard but there are holes possible.

```
<div id="seats">
   <div class="row">
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm afraid that simple css is not enough. Seat elements are generated by server-side code and every of them is absolutely positioned (by inline css) So it seems that some sort of JS code is necessary

Comment: Add your css in order to help you. or set a fiddle or jsbin.

Comment: Try reading bootstrap css. They contain some classes like col-xs, col-sm, col-md,etc         http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @Igle I'm aware of this. Problem is that I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: Please edit your question, I have accidentally downvoted it, although I wanted upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can give simple percents in the absolute coordinates. But you need to give the different positions to the different member "seat" classes, which is highly impractical.

I think in your case the best solution were some like:

```
<style>
.seats {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}

.seat {
   display: inline-block;
   position: static;
   width: 25%;
   height: 10%;
}
</style>
<div id="seats">
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
   <input type="button" class="seat"/>
</div>
```

I would yet suggest a little bit of learning about the fluid design.

Here is a solution if you need always and *only* absolute tags, probably because of some very esoteric cause:

```
<style>
#seat1 {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 13%;
   right: 19%;
   top: 17%;
   bottom: 29%;
}

#seat2 {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 18%;
   right: 23%;
   top: 45%;
   bottom: 67;
}

// And any other seat-declaration, with its absolute coordinates!

</style>
<div id="seats">
   <input type="button" id="seat1"/>
   <input type="button" id="seat2"/>
   <input type="button" id="seat3"/>
   <input type="button" id="seat4"/>
   <input type="button" id="seat5"/>
   <input type="button" id="seat6"/>
</div>
```

So will do it exactly what you wrote here.

But warn: I am sure, that you does something terrible.

Comment: It's not that easy. A I said  - elements must be absolutely positioned because the whole seat structure is irregular.

Comment: I developed my answer.

Comment: Ok, but currently I think my current solution works. Is it so?